# On MacOS, how do you delete history without deleting cookies and cache?

Tags: macos, safari

I can't seem to find the option to do so. Also, I'm on Big Sur if that's relevant.

Comment: Hi @kirbyyyyy, have you tried to go to History > Clear History? It shouldn’t remove cookies and cache.

Comment: It does for me, when I press the Clear History button it tells me this "Clearing history will remove related cookies and other website data".

Comment: When in History tab, can you press CMD + A then Delete?

Comment: @Lulucmy that works great, thank you. Can I flag your answer as the correct one or something?

Comment: Great! Someone else already posted my answer, so just upvote him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open safari and press ⌘Y, then press ⌘A, right click (Or control click) and select delete.

If you just want to delete some, then ⌘Click the days or sites you want to delete and then right click (Or control click) and select delete.